# Normalisation for pressure for low and high flow speed regimes: what is the explanation behind it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

In the book of *Theoretical microfluidics* by Bruus, at page 26 it is given that

> $$
> p=\frac{\eta V_{0}}{L_{0}} \tilde{p}=P_{0} \tilde{p}
> $$
> Note that a quantity often can be made dimensionless in more than one way. Regarding the pressure, it is, for example, possible to choose $P_{0}$ either as $\eta V_{0} / L_{0}$ or as $\rho V_{0}{ }^{2}$. **The former gives the scale of pressure in the case of small velocities, such as in microfluidics, whereas the latter is used at high velocities.**
> (the emphasis is mine)

But the author doesn't explain why it is the case, namely just one normalisation is for low speed regime and the other for high speed.

Comment: The first normalization focuses on the viscous nature of the flow.  The 2nd normalization focuses on the high momentum of the flow (if that is the case).

Comment: @ChetMiller I appreciate the willingness to help but your comment is just rephrasing what the author says. I'm looking an actual physical explanation

Comment: In any specific problem, I always do it both ways and then use my judgment to decide which de-dimensionalization strikes me as more appropriate.

Comment: @ChetMiller Then let me rephrase my question according to you comment: how do you decide which one is more appropriate? what criteria are you using?

Comment: I would tend to use $\frac{\eta V_0}{L_0}$ for low Reynolds number situations and $\rho V_0^2$ for high Reynolds number situations.

Comment: @ChetMiller why?

Comment: At low Reynolds numbers, viscous forces dominate, and in the limit of zero Reynolds number, we have creeping flow, in which momentum forces play no role.  At high Reynolds numbers, inertial forces dominate, and we tend to have boundary layer flows where viscous forces are significant only near walls (within the boundary later).

Comment: @ChetMiller and how do you use this information to determine which normalisation to use?

Comment: I already explained that two comments ago.  There is no bright line of Re that I use to determine which de-dimensionalization I use.  Sometimes I carry it through both ways for quite a while before I decide on one or the other.  But, of course, in a creeping flow situation (like high viscosity polymer flow), I would use the viscosity version and in a boundary layer situation, I would gravitate to the inertial version.  You would do better spending your valuable time solving lots of sample textbook problems than to speculate on this so much.  You'll get the idea.